# If the secondary thread is created by NSThread could change detach state to joinable state?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, pthreads, nsthread

I know the default state of secondary thread created by `NSThread` is `detached`, I want to know if I could change the state to `joinable` use some api of `NSThread` rather than `pthread`?

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple's thread management guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2

If you do want to create joinable threads, the only way to do so is using POSIX threads.
POSIX creates threads as joinable by default. To mark a thread as detached or joinable, modify the thread attributes using the pthread_attr_setdetachstate function prior to creating the thread. After the thread begins, you can change a joinable thread to a detached thread by calling the pthread_detach function. For more information about these POSIX thread functions, see the pthread man page. For information on how to join with a thread, see the pthread_join man page.